# Regex only found one result at a time in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

We're trying to use a simple regular expression to find some tags in a template string. The regex is simply `<[^<>]*>`, as our tags are like `<document:name>`.

We tried it on some testing website, like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) and within CodenameOne. All work as expected, our tags are detected, BUT within CN1 the regex only match one tag at a time altough the RE API use an int to select the matching string.

Is there a flag or something else to set in order to have multiple matches ?

We have a workaround, as shown in the test code, but we'd prefer to use the API in the right way.

Here is the test code we use for regex :

```
Form hi = new Form("Regex Tester", new BorderLayout());
Button test = new Button("Test RE");
TextField regex = new TextField("<[^<>]*>");
TextArea testString = new TextArea("Partner : <partner:label> \r\n" + 
        "Contact : <contact:lastname> static text with < <contact:firstname>");
Container results = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
Container north = BoxLayout.encloseY(regex, testString, test);

hi.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, north).add(BorderLayout.CENTER, results);

test.addActionListener(e->{
    results.removeAll();
    RE r = new RE(regex.getText());

    if(r.match(testString.getText()))
    {
        results.add(new Label("Regex matched !"));
        results.add(new Label("Results found : " + r.getParenCount()));
        for(int i = 0; i < r.getParenCount(); i++)
            results.add(new Label("" + r.getParen(i)));

        // Since it catches only one string at a time, here is a workaround
        results.add(new Label("======= V2 ======="));

        String testStr = testString.getText();
        int index = 0;
        int trueCount = 0;
        while(r.match(testStr, index))
        {
            results.add(new Label("Results found : " + r.getParenCount()));
            for(int i = 0; i < r.getParenCount(); i++)
            {
                results.add(new Label("" + r.getParen(i)));
                trueCount++;
            }
            index = r.getParenEnd(r.getParenCount() -1);
        }
        results.add(new Label("True count : " + trueCount));
    }
    else
        results.add(new Label("Regex didn't match..."));
    hi.forceRevalidate();
});

hi.show();
```

Here is the resulting "log" shown on screen :

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see in the green part, the API does only found one result but should found three, as seen in the workaround red part.

Comment: I just ran your code and got 3 results with true count == 3

Comment: The `trueCount` is calculated by the workaround part, this value should be returned by the `getParenCount` call, without the need of a workaround, so does the `RE` needs flags or other parameters to match multiple Strings at once ? 
If you check the screenshot, the 'results found' value in the green part should be 3, not only 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and lessons on regular expression, I've understood how this API works.

"Parenthesized subexpressions" refer to capture groups, that I didn't even know existed when I asked this question. So it has nothing to do about results, except that the first capture group is always the full match.

The RE API doesn't seem to be able to capture multiple matches at once, it appears that what I thought to be a workaround is in fact the right way to get all matches from a string, except that if we want only matches, we need to call `getParen()` with the index 0.

If I use the regex `(\w+ (\d+))` on values :

```
Jan 1987
May 1969
Aug 2011
```

This will be the result :

[image: regex result]

So the API is fully working, I just need to add some helper methods in our internal library to use it easier. Maybe I'll try to write a better documentation for `RE`, if I have time. As it is now, it's barely understandable for a developer that is not well versed in regex IMHO.

Thanks Shai for pointing me the right direction !

Comment: I hope you will find the time to send a PR with a better documentation :)

Comment: I think I'll code some helper methods tonight, the PR will maybe contains a bit more than just a better doc :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the API. Honestly, I'm not too sure I understand the API myself but it seems that `getParenCount()` doesn't work like that.

The JavaDoc of the API says: "Returns the number of parenthesized subexpressions available after a successful match."

Which I'm guessing would mean something like:

```
<partner:label1 <partner:label2> <partner:label3>>
```

So when it returns label1 it should be 2. But this is a bit of a guess.